# Could not compile Cordova project in Android studio with Cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova

I'm new to cordova development, but i have some experience with native Android. I've received smth that I was told, is a cordova project. It has no top-level config.xml and no WWW directory, but has android and ios directories, which also would not compile as a project. Could it be that it is only a part of the project or I am missing something?

File tree

```
top level dirs-> 
            .idea
            android
            ios
            iosmobile
            unpacked
            win10
          files->             
            common.gradle
```

Comment: Please post your file tree.

Comment: done, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the file structure, it doesn't seem to be a cordova project. A cordova project will have a structure like :

```
myapp/
|-- config.xml
|-- hooks/
|-- merges/
| | |-- android/
| | |-- windows/
| | |-- ios/
|-- www/
|-- platforms/
| |-- android/
| |-- windows/
| |-- ios/
|-- plugins/
  |--cordova-plugin-camera/
```

If it is a cordova project, its files have been considerably modified. Its possibly a react native project, though I can't be certain. 
Cordova directory structure : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/#directory-structure

React Native project structure : https://www.reactnative.guide/5-project-structure-and-start-building-some-app/5.0-intro.html